# Downloading a file from a link in a GridView inside an UpdatePanel fails

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, file-upload, webforms

I am trying to save a file (image, word, pdf or any type) in a database via a FileUpload control in asp.net (i.e. **file.Docx etc**). I then wish to display the file name as a link in a GridView so when the user clicks it, the file will be downloaded.

I have tried everything. In debugging it shows nothing. It reaches the end of Response.End but downloads nothing.

GridView:

```
<asp:TemplateField>
     <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:LinkButton ID="btnLinkDownloadTender" runat="server" Text='<%#  Eval("UploadedTenderPath") %>'CommandArgument='<%# Eval("UploadedTenderPath") %>' OnClick="DownloadTender"></asp:LinkButton>
     </ItemTemplate>
 </asp:TemplateField>
```

Upload:

```
protected void UploadTender()
{
    try
    {
        if (FileUpload1.HasFile)
        {
            string fileName = Path.GetFileName(FileUpload1.FileName);
            FileUpload1.PostedFile.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/UploadedTenders/") + fileName);

            HdnFieldUploadedTender.Value = fileName;

            ResultLabel.ResultLabelAttributes("Tender Uploaded", ProjectUserControls.Enums.ResultLabel_Color.Red);
            ResultPanel.Controls.Add(ResultLabel);
        }
        else
        {
            ResultLabel.ResultLabelAttributes("No file specified", ProjectUserControls.Enums.ResultLabel_Color.Red);
            ResultPanel.Controls.Add(ResultLabel);
        }
    } 
}
```

Download:

```
protected void DownloadTender(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string filePath = (sender as LinkButton).CommandArgument;

    Response.ContentType = ContentType;
    Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + Path.GetFileName(filePath) );
    Response.Write(filePath);
    Response.End();
}
```

Folder structure:

[image]

Comment: You are just outputting the path to the file as a string, not the actual file.

Comment: @DavidG Help me out sir, i have put all my learning into it but not working, I am on very tight deadline and can't afford to waste more time

Comment: If you can't Google "send file asp.net" then I doubt anyone can truly help you :)

Comment: Is your gridview in an updatepanel

Comment: yes sir , in update panel, chrome

Comment: error

{Unable to evaluate expression because the code is optimized or a native frame is on top of the call stack.}

Comment: Update panel is causing the problem see my answer below which I edited

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try the following,
also give us more information about your page. also if you are using chrome check that chrome isn't blocking it

```
var fileInfo = new FileInfo(filePath);
Response.Clear();
Response.Buffer = true;
Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + fileInfo.Name);
Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", fileInfo.Length.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
Response.BinaryWrite(File.ReadAllBytes(fileInfo.FullName));
Response.Flush();
Response.End();
```

Edit:
In your gridview Row Databound add the following

```
LinkButton lb = e.Row.FindControl("btnLinkDownloadTender") as LinkButton;
if (lb != null)
     ScriptManager.GetCurrent(this).RegisterPostBackControl(lb);
```

The above code will register the LinkButton to cause a Full Postback, this will allow the Download to succeed, the same will apply when doing an upload of a file in an Update Panel

Comment: error 

{Unable to evaluate expression because the code is optimized or a native frame is on top of the call stack.}

Comment: See my edit, that is the code I am currently using on another web app, previous code I created a .ashx file

Comment: Update panel is causing your download to fail

Answer (score 4):

Replace `AppendHeader` to `AddHeader`

```
string fullFilePath = Server.MapPath("~/UploadedTenders/") + filePath;
Response.Clear();
Response.ClearHeaders();
Response.ClearContent();
Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + fullFilePath );
Response.ContentType = ContentType;
Response.TransmitFile(fullFilePath);
```

Comment: and I am picking file name from database only like File.png, file.docx etc

Comment: There's a space missing between `Text` attribute and `CommandArgument` attribute in your `LinkButton`

Comment: What's the value of your filePath ?

Comment: 'picture.png', it is picked from databse

Comment: I am saving only picture.png in database

Comment: error

{Unable to evaluate expression because the code is optimized or a native frame is on top of the call stack.}

Comment: I edited my answer. If your images are located to `UploadedTenders`, add a Server.MapPath to build the full path to your image.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92957/discussion-between-krlzlx-and-covert).

Answer (score 4):

try this:

```
Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + file_name);
Response.WriteFile(filePath);
Response.Flush();
Response.End();
```

Comment: error {Unable to evaluate expression because the code is optimized or a native frame is on top of the call stack.}

Comment: Instead of Response.Write in "DownloadTender" method use Response.WriteFile(). { string filePath = (sender as LinkButton).CommandArgument;
    Response.ContentType = ContentType;
    Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + Path.GetFileName(filePath));
    Response.WriteFile(filePath);
    Response.End();}